# Trouble Posing Rigged Model

Tags: rigify, pose-mode

I followed the tutorials and rigged a model using rigify. Visually, everything appears to be correct, but when I go into pose mode and adjust the rig, the model doesn't move with it. It seems like I did something wrong, but I sure can't figure out what it is.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your generated rig is offset because your metarig's transform wasn't applied when you generated the rig. Make sure in the side panel(N key toggle)<Transform, that location, rotation, scale of your metarig is 0,0,0. If is one mesh, automatic weights will work. For hard objects, parent them to specific bones in your mesh(View bones by clicking what is circled in red here as blue. After selecting your object, go into pose mode and with ctrl+p<bone. Also try going into weight paint mode and checking each Vertex group, found when selecting your mesh then in Object data properties<Vertex groups.
[image]

It can also be an issue with your mesh. Recalculate normals with Shift N, remove non-manifold geometry, found under Select<Select all by Trait<Non-Manifold, and look for holes in your model.